# How do I set HTML content to title attribute of an image tag in Angular 12

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular12

I am trying to set HTML content to the title attribute of an image tag which comes from the backend like below.

```html
<span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;"> <sup>superscript</sup> </span>
```

When I set the title using property binding and DOM sanitization, when I hover on the image it supposed to show rendered HTML but it is showing direct HTML content as it coming from the backend.

I have created the [Slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7pd4lk?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for the issue.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title attribute accepts string and it displays as it is. In case you are looking for a functionality like tooltip, you can position the span relative to the image and then change the display property on mouseover of image.

Answer (score 0):

is your goal similar to this? take a look if you haven't seen it yet.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-insert-html-into-view-from-angularjs-controller/